# Is there an equivalent to CPU Load but for Android, if so how do I do check it?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

This is my first unity project for android and I managed to install it on my phone after building the app. And I want to check the app's performance/CPU load or something using my android phone, how do I do it?.

I've done similar things with my normal projects where the project is for the PC only and ask my friend how to check the CPU Load for that game.

I've tried building the app for the pc but I know that's not the correct way to do it and I couldn't find something similar searching in the net or youtube or maybe I'm just not trying hard enough

Answer (score 0):

If you install the debug version you will check the performance via Android Studio.
[link to doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler?hl=en)